# Adding numbers to each line in a file in haxe language

Tags: file, numbers, haxe

Need some help, writing a program that will read the text from a file, but will 
put at the beginning of each line a number, in such a way that each line is numbered in ascending order
example:

file1

a

b

c

What I want to see:

1: a

2: b

3: c

Comment: What have you written so far?  In order to get real help you should show some effort on your part.

Answer (score 1):

Process:

- Read contents of file into a `String`
- Split by line ending into `Array<String>`
- Iterate and mutate contents line by line
- Join by line ending back into a `String`
- Write back into file

Sample code for any `sys` target:

```
var arr = sys.File.getContent('file.txt').split("\n");

for(i in 0...arr.length) {
    arr[i] = (i+1) + ": " + arr[i];
}

sys.File.saveContent('file.txt', arr.join("\n"));
```